# Deleting an avd file

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to delete some files to open up some space.

While I have been searching files, I have came to the following folder

```
/Users/.android/avd
```

and there is a `avd` folder where there is a `AVD_for_Nexus_7` file which takes up **32.7** gb.

Is it safe to delete?

[image]

and also this avd (google nexus 7) does not even show up on Android Virtual Device Manager.

[image]

Comment: Off-topic, try [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/) to clear out cache etc, or [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) to see what is using the most space on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have it listed as a virtual device, then yes, it is safe to delete.

However, that Xamarin device doesn't seem to have any model name. If you click "Repair Device", does it repair itself into a Nexus 7?

Either way, 32GB is much larger than the 1GB reported, so creating a new AVD is good idea.

Comment: Is it safe to delete directly through folder/file system? In other words, just deleting the file might causes any issues?

Comment: Yes, it's safe. The worst that can possibly happen is you lose a virtual device that wasn't working correctly!